# Can VS Code work with a jupyterlab server? Not jupyterhub

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just want to know if VS Code can work with jupyterlab server, not jupyterhub (I know the latter works well)

I tried to connect, but it doesn't work. I have also question with the jupyterhub connection, it doesn't make sense if the working folder is not on the hub. What is the purpose of that connection, just use the remote computer resource?